# Inline output: Change small p-values to p < 0.001 in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, inline

I have an object `one` that contains the results of a kruskal-wallis test. The p-value is really tiny i.e. 6.86e-09. Is there a way in inline code in R markdown to say p < 0.0001 instead of writing the exact p-value?

```r
one <- kruskal.test(Petal.Width ~ Species, data = iris)
```

I have tried:

```markdown
There was a statistically significant difference in the Petal Width between species
H(`r one[[2]]`) = `r round(one[[1]], 3)`, *p* = `r round(one[[3]], 11)`.
```

And:

```markdown
`r if(one[[3]] < 0.0001){ print("< 0.0001") } else { round(one[[3]], 4) }`
```

Desired output:

There was a statistically significant difference in the Petal Width between species H(2) = 131.19,  *p* < 0.0001.

There are lot's out there on how to recode into significance codes etc, but not really how to do this for inline code. I am new to this so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a vectorised `ifelse` for this. If the value is smaller than 0.0001, print a "<" symbol together with 0.0001, else print a "=" symbol with the actual rounded value.

An addition `one[[2]]` is included to demonstrate the case where the value is greater than 0.0001.

You can add an extra `ifelse` statement at the beginning of your sentence (`ifelse(one[[3]] < 0.0001, "was", "wasn't")`) to determine whether it is statistically significant or not.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
date: "2023-01-10"
---

```{r}
one <- kruskal.test(Petal.Width ~ Species, data = iris)
```

There `r ifelse(one[[3]] < 0.0001, "was", "wasn't")` a statistically significant difference in the Petal Width between species H(`r one[[2]]`) = `r round(one[[1]], 3)`, p `r ifelse(one[[3]] < 0.0001, paste("<", 0.0001), paste("=", round(one[[3]], 4)))`.

There `r ifelse(one[[2]] < 0.0001, "was", "wasn't")` a statistically significant difference in the Petal Width between species H(`r one[[2]]`) = `r round(one[[1]], 3)`, p `r ifelse(one[[2]] < 0.0001, paste("<", 0.0001), paste("=", round(one[[2]], 4)))`.
````

Rmarkdown PDF output example:

[image: rmd_out]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `format.pval()` to format p-values.

```r
format.pval(one$p.value, eps = 0.0001, scientific = FALSE)
# [1] "< 0.0001"
```

where `eps` is a threshold; those less than `eps` are formatted as `"< [eps]"` (where `[eps]` stands for `format(eps, digits)`).

Answer (score 1):

For one, the print statement is probably unnecessary.
On my end, it helped splitting the ifelse out of the inline, writing its result to a variable, and then just calling on that variable in the inline

```r
one <- kruskal.test(Petal.Width ~ Species, data = iris)
pval <- if(one[[3]] < 0.0001){"< 0.0001"}else{round(one[[3]], 4)}
```

There was a statistically significant difference in the Petal Width between species H(`r one[[2]]`) = `r round(one[[1]], 3)`, p = `r pval`.

If you only have two conditions you can also use ifelse -

```r
pval <- ifelse(one[[3]] < 0.0001, "< 0.0001", round(one[[3]],4))
```